# Sorting Specific Column in a GridView after a DataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have given an access to stored procedure, which i'm not able to edit.
This Stored Procedure returns a Table with 2 Column, what I did is set a GridView's DataSource using SQLDataSource in this stored procedure. but I want this GridView to Sort an specific column to descending whenever this GridView Loads.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="Black" 
                        Width="58%" Height="125px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                        PageSize="5" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOccur" HeaderText="Login Date" 
                                SortExpression="DateOccur" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalMinutesPlayed" HeaderText="Total Minutes" 
                                SortExpression="TotalMinutesPlayed" />
                        </Columns>
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EFEFEF" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the Gridview.Sort method
[See Here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx)

Comment: hi at what event should I put this Method? I tried it in DataBound and Sorting event but doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't sort it by editing the SQL itself, you can sort it programmatically by binding a DataView object to the datasource, specifying a Sort expression for the DataView, and then binding the DataGrid to the DataView object.

For a walkthrough of some example code, [see here](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/sortingaspgrid.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was using a slightly modified version of the example code I found on MSDN.

[Gridview Sort Example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx#Y374)

By combining the example I found with the SortExpression property I can sort on any column even using proprietary sorts my specification called for.